# Set ItemsSource to DataTable Item

Tags: sql, wpf, vb.net, ado.net

I am trying to set the itemssource for my WPF-based VB 2010 project to a datatable item. The datatable is "roster_table" and the column name I want to display the items from in the list box is "DATA_NAME". The listbox is "lstNames".

My apologies if this is a dumb question, but I can't find a straight answer anywhere. How do I set the itemssource for the listbox to the datatable's column, as described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
lstNames.ItemsSource = roster_table;
lstNames.DisplayMemberPath = "DATA_NAME";
```

to set value to the item

```
lstNames.SelectedValuePath = "YOUR_ID";
```

Comment: YEEEEEEEEEEEES! I finally have the roster working! Thank you so much for your help! This makes my day. :) God bless.